# Cannot Send Video Files Using Twilio's Whatsapp API

Tags: api, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I am Currently on a Project Which Captures a Video Detects for a Light Source in it and if The source Exists The Video gets Recorded and saved in [cloudinary.com](https://cloudinary.com),
What I did after was i passed the cloudinary url into the media_url of twilio create function,
There are no error codes in the response, the status is 'queued' and The dashboard at twilio shows nothing.

Where Would The Problem Be?